# Reading signed email with java mail api

Tags: java, email

I am using java mail version 1.5 for fetching emails from email server. For unsigned emails I don't have problem.Following test code works. But if there is a signed email, since java mail returns message content as **BASE64DecoderStream**, I dont know how to handle it.My question is how fetching signed email differs from fetching unsigned emails if I don't have verification of email and another question is what if I want to verify email signature, how to do that using Bouncy Castle api ?

```
        //Assume there is a javax.mail.Message object here
        Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
        for (Address address : in) {
            System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
        }
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
        System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
        System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
        System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
```